# iOS 8 UIImagePickerController allowsEditing crash

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

Have anyone noticed that if you use `UIImagePickerController` and `allowsEditing = YES` in iOS 8, your app will crash after the editing view being presented.

```
*** -[PUUIImageViewController traitCollection]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f8d714ab5e0
```

I can find few information about this `PUUIImageViewController`. It seems like a new class in iOS 8.

I've spent 2 days on my code and started thinking this may be a bug in iOS 8.
Any ideas?

Here's my code for opening the `UIImagePickerController`

```
- (void)picButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {


            self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
            self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
            self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{

            }];
        }

}
```

As for `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];


}
```

The app crashes after the controller dismiss `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Can we see the code related to setting up the UIImagePicker please? I might know the answer too why.

Comment: Oh yeah sure! I thought my setting was simply basic setting so I didn't put it. Edited. Thank you :)

Comment: I think it should be `[self.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];`

Comment: Yeah, you're dismissing the entire view controller.